# vb.net working with currency values in text boxes

Tags: vb.net, formatting, currency-formatting

I've got a simple form in my app used for adding orders.

It contains two textbox controls, 'neworder_costprice' and 'neworder_saleprice'.
I also have a slider control, markup_percent', which can be a value between 0 and 100 at increments of 10.

I'm trying to make it so if the user types in "1.20" for example in the costprice textbox, the saleprice textbox will automatically populate with the value of costprice + markup_percent.

I've tried a few different ways of getting this to work, but nothing seems to want to do it for me! Can anyone point out the error of my ways?

The following is my current code from a 'workoutsaleprice()' function which is called upon costprice.valuechanged....

```
tech_neworder_costprice.Text = String.Format("{0:n2}", neworder_costprice.Text)           

Dim costprice As Double = neworder_costprice.Text
Dim markup As Integer = percent_slider.Value

Dim saleprice As Double = ((costprice / 100) * markup) + costprice
neworder_saleprice.Text = saleprice.ToString
```

Comment: You should use `NumericUpDown` when you will restrict input to numbers. Otherwise how do you handle mistakes like `1..20`?

Comment: I was going to do validate on submit... if the data is incorrect then no submit and give user an error saying sort yourself out :)

Comment: OK you can do that, but it increases the complexity. This is what `NumericUpDown` is for :).

Comment: Ok, well I've not used NumericUpDown before, so i'll give it a go. 
Can i just reference the values and as in my code above and vb will know whats going on?

Comment: Verdolino, you beauty! that did the trick perfectly! 
Do you want to add your answer as an answer so i can tick it off and you get the credit? :)

Comment: can you im me dude? I have another small problem that i know will be something silly. :)

Comment: No im's on SO. If you have another question, post it and link to it, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NumericUpDown` for numeric input instead of a `TextBox`. Validation is handled automatically so it is guaranteed to never have a non numeric value.

You would instead use the `NumericUpDown.Value` property of type Decimal to perform numeric operations.

Comment: Hugely appriciated Verdolino :)